# Building UWP project in GitHub Action with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, uwp, msbuild, github-actions

I'm trying to build a UWP project as part of a Github Actions Workflow.

In my YAML I am building and running a separate project so that I can debug my CICD pipeline locally. This separate project uses msbuild to build my main UWP project. Prior to recent changes (Github upgrading to Windows Server 2022 as the default runner + my team starting to use language features which require VS2022) this worked fine. Now I'm struggling to get things to build.

I've specified in my YAML to use Windows Server 2019 and Visual Studio 2022.

The msbuild command I run consists of:

```cs
var command = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe";
var x86Arguments = $@"ApplicationName /restore /p:Configuration=Release /p:Verbosity=minimal /p:Platform=x86 /p:AppxBundle=Never /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload";
```

The error I'm hitting is:

> error MSB4019: The imported project
> "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v17.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets"
> was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v17.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets"
> is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I've tried to locate the targets file in the github runner and the only copy of it is from the VS2019 installation.

I've tried various attempts at targeting this file, which don't work.

Has anyone managed to build UWP apps with msbuild with VS2022 in a Github Workflow?